# Django video in template, seems to detect media but not working

Tags: django, html5-video

Please i have been working on this for a while but don't seem to find the problem. I am trying to get a video from the uploaded files to work on the template,but all i keep getting is a blank video, although when i view the  page source or inspect the video element, it seems to be pointing to the right video, and all solutions i have tried to make this work proved abortive.
Below are my codes:

MY MODEL:

```
class Sermon(models.Model):
topic = models.CharField('Topic', max_length=50)
pub_date  = models.DateField('Sermon Date')
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
last_edited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
type = models.CharField('Type', max_length=50, choices=sermon_chioices)
audio = models.FileField(upload_to='audios', default="Not Available", blank=True, validators=[validate_audio_extension], null=True)
video = models.FileField(upload_to='videos', default="Not Available", blank=True)#can be changed if the video will recide in the system
outlines = models.FileField(upload_to="outlines", default="Not Available", blank=True,)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="User", editable=False)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-pub_date']

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.topic

def get_absolute_url(self):
    #return reverse('sermon_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
    return reverse('sermon_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

MY VIEW:

```
class SermonDetails(DetailView):
    model = Sermon
    template_name = 'agonopa/sermon_details.html'
    context_object_name = 'sermon'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SermonDetails, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #context['sermons'] = Sermon.objects.all()
        return context

#Sunday Service List
class SundayServiceSermonList(ListView):
    model = Sermon
    template_name = 'agonopa/sermon.html'
    context_object_name = 'sermon_list' #'ss_sermon_list'
    queryset = Sermon.objects.filter(type__exact="SUNDAY SERVICE")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SundayServiceSermonList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Sunday Service'
        return context
```

MY TEMPLATE:

```
{% if sermon %}
    <h3>{{ sermon.topic}}</h3>
    {{sermon.outline}}
    {{ sermon.pub_date}}

 {% endif %}
 <video  loop class="embed-responsive-item thumbnails" controls>
        <source src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{{sermon.video.url}}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

MY MEDIA SETTINGS:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'churchsite_static_root','media_root')
```

The Server returns things like this in the terminal:

```
[28/Nov/2015 11:38:10]"GET /agonopa/sermon/3/ HTTP/1.1" 200 377
[28/Nov/2015 11:38:10]"GET /media/videos/wowo_Boyz_5gQAbzG.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 404 2344
```

Thanks for your help in advance, and for further clarification on the question pls do let me know. 
It should be noted, that i have tried many solutions from stakeoverflow, and several blogs but none seems to works, so i had to post it here.

Comment: Is this served using `runserver`? What does your site's `urls.py` look like?

Comment: Also, if you go into `./manage.py shell`, what does `settings.MERDIA_ROOT` look like? You seem to have a lot more `os.path.dirname()`'s, etc. than I use. (or is your media settings file nested really deep?)

Comment: it is serveed using runserver,  and the url here is included as an app, before the app url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply imported settings, and then static, and also added the if Debug: to my urls.py, thus the program looked as below:

Urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from agonopa.views import SermonMonthArchiveView, SermonYearArchiveView

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'churchsite.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^$', 'agonopa.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^agonopa/', include('agonopa.urls')),
    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),


]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

That's all to it. Thanks to Mike Covington in all.
Also note, that the media settings, template and other files above didn't change for the whole stuff to work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your `MEDIA_ROOT` is way too high (as in no longer within your project). When I use the settings you use, I get a media root directory of `../../../churchsite_static_root/media_root/` relative to your `settings.py` file. I would expect `churchsite_static_root` to be one directory up from `settings.py` (or at the same level as `manage.py`).

Go into Django shell and check the media root path to see if it seems reasonable (and confirm that your files are actually there):

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.MEDIA_ROOT
```

Try the following in your `settings.py` and let me know if it helps:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'churchsite_static_root', 'media_root')
```

Be sure you have something like this in your site's `urls.py` if using `python manage.py runserver`:

```
# For Django>=1.8:
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

# For Django<1.8:
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

Comment: Thanks mike, but it still didn't work, but keeps on saying " 'module' object is not callable"

Comment: What is giving this error/what is the full error? Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: @Emack333 If the `urls.py` snippet is what is causing the error and you are using a version of Django prior to 1.8, try something like the alternate snippet that I've updated the answer with.

Comment: Finally mike it worked, the issue was  from the way i imported my static, i did it the wrong way i.e: "from django.conf.urls import static" instead of "from django.conf.urls.static import static", and then added the if settings.DEBUG for Django1.8, but my settings still remained as it was initially. Thanks a million.